# Excel Lookup with summed up [result_vector]

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using the lookup-function in Excel and I'm having troubles calculating the total of the result cells.
Basically, I'm trying to look for a key (`[@Key]`) in column A. Finally the value displayed should be the sum up of the occurences in column A with the values of column B

Here's an example:

```
+-----+-----+  +------+-------+
+  A  +  B  +  +  Key + Total +
+-----+-----+  +------+-------+
+ 1.1 +  12 +  +  1.1 +    50 +
+-----+-----+  +------+-------+
+ 1.2 +  72 +  +  1.2 +   100 +
+-----+-----+  +------+-------+
+ 1.1 +  18 +
+-----+-----+
+ 1.1 +  20 +
+-----+-----+
+ 1.2 +  28 +
+-----+-----+
```

I tried to use `=LOOKUP([@Key];A:A;SUM(B:B))`, but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SUMIF](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumif-HP005209292.aspx):

```
=SUMIF(A:A;[@Key];B:B)
```

- first parameter, `A:A`, is criteria range
- second parameter, `[@Key]`, is criteria for searching
- and third parameter, `B:B`, is sum range

[image]